# How do I get any process's network traffic from memory?

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, hook, dll-injection

I want to **dump network traffic** from **any application** in Windows. But I don't want to use any proxy or listen to socket. I just want to read it from **memory**.

I could do it with Strace in linux. Can you suggest a solution for Windows? As a result of my research, I found Echo Mirage. But I could not find which dll(winapi) uses this process.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a system tool such as Network Monitor and filtering the resulting traffic down to your specific port ? The following implies that it's possible https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/2006/10/17/intro-to-filtering-with-network-monitor-3-0/

Comment: Yes, I did, but it doesn't meet my needs. I need to read send/recv packets through system calls.

Answer (score 0):

To get the winsock traffic you would want to hook the send & recv functions which are exported by ws2_32.dll and log the arguments.

If the traffic is HTTP you should use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

For logging non HTTP traffic for a specific process on Windows the best tool (despite being deprecated) is [Message Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-analyzer/microsoft-message-analyzer-operating-guide)